# Connect with mongodb server on digital ocean

Tags: mongodb, digital-ocean

I followed 
[DigitalOcean Mongodb Install](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-18-04)

```
  sudo ufw allow from your_other_server_ip/32 to any
```

I set your other server as 127.0.01 as I will be connecting it with express local device as localhost:3000

```
  sudo ufw allow from 127.0.0.1/32 to any
```

and created admin user.

I have  also updated mongodb.conf to

```
 logappend=true

 bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,139.**.*.**
 port = 27017
```

How can I make connection with mongoose now.

I tried with a gui with ssh connection and it worked.

How can I connect it with HTTP URL.

**EDIT - 1**

I installed mongodb

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-18-04

And with

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04#part-two-securing-mongodb

Step 3 — Testing the Remote Connection

I am getting

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://139.**.*.***:27017/
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
```

And running

```
> show users
{
"_id" : "testdb.testusr",
"user" : "testusr",
"db" : "testdb",
"roles" : [
{
"role" : "readWrite",
"db" : "testdb"
}
]
}
```

If i try to connect with mongoose with below code

```
 var connectionString = "mongodb://testusr:testpwd@139.**.*.***:27017/testdb";

mongoose
.connect(connectionString, {
keepAlive: 1,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useNewUrlParser: true,
})
.then(() => console.log('DB Connected!'))
.catch(err => {
console.log(`DB Connection Error: ${err.message}`);
});
```

I am getting below output

DB Connection Error: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms